# How to find intersection of sets

Tags: c++, c, math

I have N number of sets of let us say integers. Now I want a function, which finds me the intersection of those sets. For example, for the following

```
Set1 = { A, D, E, F, G, L }
Set2 = { N, K, E, G, B, C }
Set3 = { K, P, Q, E, F, G }
Set4 = { Z, Y, C, G, F, E }
```

Since E and G is in every set, I should get `{ E, G }` as output. What is the easiest way to do this. I know it is not very difficult to write your own code to do this, but perhaps there is already an STL or any other library function to this, in which I'm interested.

Comment: Judging from your expected output, you want to *intersect* the sets, not _unite_ them.

Comment: I suggest you start by reviewing the definitions of `union` and `intersection` wrt sets.

Comment: Take a look to http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set#C

Comment: Just a thought: if each of your sets has NO duplicate elements (which seems to be the case), then just create a hash table that counts how many times each item as been inserted in the table... If this count equals the number of sets, then you have your answer.

Comment: @Mihai Todor: That is indeed a very good and succint method!

Comment: @MihaiTodor If these are actual sets (i.e. no duplicates), your answer is not only good; it is optimal, since it would be O(N), where N is the number of elements in all sets total (common or otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

Two possible solutions I can think of

1. Store your sets in vectors. Sort the vectors using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), and compute set intersection using [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)
2. Store your sets in [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), which causes the elements to be sorted anyway, and use `std::set_intersection`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that std::set was always sorted.

Comment: It is. The class `std::unordered_set`, which is new in c++11, is the unordered version of std::set which instead of sorting uses a hash-table.

Answer (score 1):

See [`std::set_intersection`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/). (As pointed out already in the comments, you probably want intersection, not union.)

Comment: Maybe his sets are sorted. We don’t know, because the OP failed to inform us about the C++ representation of sets that he uses.

Comment: @Pukku I think he might be able to do better than this with a hash table, if each of his sets do not have duplicate elements.